# How to change dialog box with jQuery Mobile on OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, jquery

I have a problem with dialog box made with jQuery Mobile on OpenLayers. I want to make a popup box instead of a dialog box, but when i click the point the info for the point appears at different window instead of appearing on the map. My code is:

**js:**

```
$('#popup').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
        var li = "";
        for(var attr in selectedFeature.attributes){
            li += "<li><div style='width:25%;float:left'>" + attr + "</div><div style='width:75%;float:right'>" 
            + selectedFeature.attributes[attr] + "</div></li>";     
        }
          //alert("test");

        $("ul#details-list").empty().append(li).listview("refresh");
    });
```

Comment: you mean you want to reposition popup?

Comment: Yes..i want popup box appear on the map..instead appear different page...